# How to capture key event on canvas in Vue

Tags: javascript, canvas, vue.js, event-listener

Using Vue 2.5, I have a `canvas` with a key event listener on it:

```
<template>
    <canvas v-on:keyup.esc="abortThing"></canvas>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        abortThing() {
            console.log('you hit escape!');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem is that the listener isn't responding when I hit escape, whether or not I have already clicked on the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experimented with this for awhile and discovered that browsers don't allow canvas to be focused by default. Any other element that is active though, like a clicked button or active form, will respond to keyup events just fine.

However, there's a property called [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) that indicates whether something can be focused and in what order if you press tab (hence the name). If we set the `tabindex` to 0 then it's focused by default. I wasn't able to find documentation to explain the interaction between canvas and keyboard focus. It just seems to be something the browser is generally resisting unlike other element types.

It's a bit fickle to demonstrate in this snippet because it's basically asserting the `tabindex` for the window. You might need to click on the blue area for it to work here before hitting escape.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  template: `<div>
    <canvas tabindex="0" v-on:keyup.esc="abortThing" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:blue"></canvas>
</div>`,
  methods: {
    abortThing(event) {
      console.log(event);
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```